# I have one issue for ios device when i focus on input cursor of input does not stay fix it scrolls with page scroll

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2

I have one issue for iOS device when i focus on input cursor of input does not stay fix it scrolls with page scroll.

Added one solution for cursor issue but its behaviour is like when scroll page by dragging cursor moves and take it position again this small issue occurs other wise scrolling cursor is solved just need to check for another issue

1. First solution is give -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto to scroll-content div but when its applying it cause hard scrolling
2. Second solution is disablescroll(true) to page but it gives current behaviour that is cursor moves and then get its position

Need better solution for this issue.

Comment: is input cursor not moving along to input box after a keyboard show?

Comment: Why don't you dismiss keyboard when scrolling starts?

Comment: @MaulikBhuptani is this right to do to dissmiss keyboard when scrolling?

Comment: @Manish yes when i focus on inout keyboard automatically shows

Comment: Yes few good apps practice this behaviour and it provides a really nice user experience.

Comment: can you please provide me one example related to it?